# IE 10 iframe not rendering

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, iframe

This is in an angular app but I believe the error lies solely in IE as relates to the iframe and the src attribute. It renders fine in Chrome. It is a large app so it's hard to silo the error in a jsfiddle. Here are the pertinent pieces.

The html/angular markdown:

```
  <div ng-repeat="form in formsToPrint">
     <h5>{{ form.FormName }} - {{ form.PageStatus }}</h5>
     <iframe ng-if="form.FormId != '9' && form.FormId != '10'"
           ng-src="{{ form.PageSrcUrl }}"
           print-iframe seamless="seamless"></iframe>
      <div ng-if="form.FormId == '9'" ng-repeat="srp in srpsToPrint">
          <h5>{{ srp.SrpCode }} - {{ srp.PageStatus }}</h5>
          <iframe ng-src="{{ srp.PageSrcUrl }}"
                    print-iframe seamless="seamless"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="form.FormId == '10'" ng-repeat="srp in localPackagesToPrint">
          <h5>{{ srp.SrpCode }} - {{ srp.PageStatus }}</h5>
          <iframe ng-src="{{ srp.PageSrcUrl }}"
                    print-iframe seamless="seamless"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The angular print-iframe directive:

```
  .directive("printIframe", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.on("load", function() {
                var self = this,
                    timeout = 8000;
                if (self.src.indexOf("#/forms/8") !== -1
                    || self.src.indexOf("#/forms/5") !== -1
                    || self.src.indexOf("#/forms/36") !== -1
                    || self.src.indexOf("#/forms/9") !== -1
                    || self.src.indexOf("#/forms/10") !== -1
                    || self.src.indexOf("#/forms/19") !== -1
                    || self.src.indexOf("#/forms/37") !== -1
                    || self.src.indexOf("#/forms/38") !== -1) {
                    timeout = 8000;
                }

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(element).contents().find("div.navbar").hide();
                    $(element).contents().find("div.binder-menu").hide();
                      $(element).contents().find("div.commonButtonBarContainer").hide();
                    $(element).contents().find("textarea.notes").closest("fieldset").hide();
                    $(".formContainer.print").height("100%");
                    $(".formContainer.print").width("100%");

                    var height = $(element).contents().outerHeight();
                    var width = $(element).contents().outerWidth();

                    if (height !== 0) {
                        $(element).height(height + 100);
                        $(element).width(width + 100);
                    }

                    $(element).contents().find(".formContainer").css({ "margin-left": "25px" });

                    $(element).show();

                    scope.showPrintWindow();
                    console.dir(scope);
                }, timeout);
            });
        }
      }
  })
```

I can't inspect the PageSrcUrl property in the console but I assume it is correct because it is working in Chrome. The DOCTYPE is declared properly.

The other stackoverflow questions I've found do not address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Iframes and Angular always produce some hickups.
The problem I found for this can be easily described:

If you have got an iframe somewhere and use angular to for example set the source, the browser will start grabbing the src immediatly after the iframe is added to the DOM.

This leads to problems, often not only in IE.
The solution I have found in our project is to add a specialized lazyiframe directive which will only add the iframe to the dom as soon as all necessary attributes are evaluated (and not undefined) any more.

In your case, the problem is most likely related to `ng-src` which might lead to the following:

- iframe is added to dom with no src attribute
- ie registers iframe and grabs the source
- ie fails the iframe and stops
- src is changed but iframe is not re-loaded due to IE bug

If you need help crafting the lazyiframe directive I can provide further details.

Comment: Yes please @Nils, I'm in need of some crafting assistance :-)

Comment: I am using the following code: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8835556
You might want to change the part where append is called, so it is called as soon as you are ready (and got a valid ng-src).